# Python Error: InsertError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not None

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm creating a python script to send emails, while a template containing placeholder variables (e.g. %NAME%) which will be replaced with data from a database.

I'm using the code below, but the problem is that the variables being used as the second replace arguments may not always contain anything. If just one of those variables has a `None` value, the script ends with error `InsertError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not None`

```py
with open ("D:\Scripts\html.html", "r") as htmlfile:
    html = htmlfile.read().replace("%TRACKINGNO%", TrackingNo).replace("%COURIER%", CourierName).replace("%ORDERNO%", OrderNo).replace("%TRACKURL%", URL).replace("%DESPATCHEDDATE%", DespatchedDate).replace("%NAME%", PostalName).replace("%POSTCODE%", PostCode)
```

Is there a concise way of essentially making it so that if the variable is `None` it replaces the placeholder with an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can replace `TrackingNo` with `TrackingNo if TrackingNo is not None else ""`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
html = htmlfile.read().replace("%TRACKINGNO%", TrackingNo or "")
```

If `TrackingNo` is `None`, it'll default to `""`. (you can use any string value you like there).

If `TrackingNo` exists, it'll use the value of `TrackingNo`.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the argument to string.
For example:

```
with open ("D:\Scripts\html.html", "r") as htmlfile:
    html = htmlfile.read().replace("%TRACKINGNO%", TrackingNo).replace("%COURIER%", str(CourierName)).replace("%ORDERNO%", OrderNo).replace("%TRACKURL%", URL).replace("%DESPATCHEDDATE%", DespatchedDate).replace("%NAME%", PostalName).replace("%POSTCODE%", PostCode)
```

This will forcefully replace the second argument CourierName with a string version of the same argument. So

```
"ABCD" will remain as "ABCD"
None will be converted into "None"
```